# (Done) What part of this question of sharing contacts is unclear?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

What part of this question is unclear?

[Telling a possible romantic interest that I cannot share my current industry contacts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/telling-a-possible-romantic-interest-that-i-cannot-share-my-current-industry-con)

It seems simple enough to me. I voted to REOPEN.

Comment: The usual suspects, who seem to think that no post should remain open

Answer (score -2):

> What part of this question is unclear?

Casted the last vote and the post is open again now.

Comment: Thanks. I'd still be curious to hear from the close voters what part of the question confused them. It might help in future question editing. In case you forgot, this: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/121350/revisions tells you if you voted to close.